# SSL cert not turning green anymore

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I'm running a Drupal site and have asked about this issue pertaining specifically to the Drupal aspect of it [on Drupal Answers Stack Exchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35740/upgraded-contrib-modules-drupal-to-7-14-now-ssl-doesnt-turn-green). I know that the "Green" HTTPS URL doesn't show up because the cert itself isn't verified exactly as the CA has the cert registered. However, nothing has changed on the site (other than updates on core and modules) as far as site information or domains. Why doesn't the SSL verify like it did prior to the update?

When checking the cert I get the following:

**Website**: www.[url].com <- this was correct.
**Owner**: This website does not supply ownership information.
**Verified by**: Not specified

Prior to updating my core Drupal and associated modules, the cert would turn the URL bar green and the certificate had the proper owner and the CA as the verifier of the cert. My page URL does turn from HTTP to HTTPS on secure pages, but is only partially encrypted according to my warnings on Firefox.

ISSUED TO: is all correct.

ISSUED BY:

The **(CN)** is: Starfield Secure Certification Authority
Organization **(O)**: Starfield Technologies, Inc
Organizational Unit **(OU)**: http://certificates.starfieldtech.com/repository
**Validity**: Issued on 3/26/2012 - Expires on 3/26/2013

Comment: Check the time/date on your client and server.

Comment: "_but is **partially** encrypted according to my warnings on firefox_" could be an explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsecured content on a page served by HTTPS is a possible explanation for this problem (at least with Google Chrome it is).

You can check your SSL configuration using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

If you need futher help, please consider revealing the site's URL.

Comment: "_If you need futher help, please consider revealing the site's URL._" +1

Comment: SSL Labs will check the configuration of the domain itself; to check the full content of the page, try https://www.whynopadlock.com.